# Captive Network Assistant in Safari does not support Session Storage

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I am building an Angular 2 application. The application is bootstrapped when a user joins the wifi network and they are redirected to the application which is rendered in a Captive Portal. The application works in all the other browsers with the exception of Safari for OS X.

I cannot debug this but from researching the behavior of OS X it seems that the Captive Portal Assistant launches some limited browser which does not support Session Storage.

https://grpugh.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/an-undocumented-change-to-captive-network-assistant-settings-in-os-x-10-10-yosemite/

This is breaking my application because when the appellation is bootstrapped it needs to store flags in Session storage before it redirects the user to the login page. Those flags are what the login page uses to determine if the user entered the application via the wifi redirect or the application url.

How do I get around this problem? I have researched and have not found any solution to my problem. Our application basically works from the point of a user attempting to access the private wifi network and this needs to work on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to store the flags instead? You could even check for `window.sessionStorage` availability and fall back to cookies if it's unavailable.

Comment: CNA doesn't seem to support cookies either. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5258403?tstart=0

Comment: Wow. Then maybe pass them to the login page as a query string? Since you're doing the redirecting, you would have that ability. Getting query strings with the Angular router is a breeze.